# How to replace if a value of the column if it starts with character "N" in R

Tags: r, tabulizer, pdftools

How to replace if a value of the column (GID) starts with char "N" to ColB if the ColB is empty in
a Dataframe in R programming

**code:**

```
DataFile <- extract_tables("new.pdf",pages = c(87),
                           method = "stream", output = "data.frame", guess = TRUE)
DataFrame<-as.data.frame(DataFile)

#removing No. and A# from columns
df2<-subset(DataFrame, Group!="No." & Group!="A#")
```

**output:**

```
GID    ColA    ColB 
1       2       2
2       3       4
3       5       4
4       6       5
5       6       5
NG1     8 
MG2     8       1
MG3     8       1
NG4     8
```

**Expected output**

```
GID    ColA    ColB 
1       2       2
2       3       4
3       5       4
4       6       5
5       6       5
NG1     8       N
MG2     8       1
MG3     8       1
NG4     8       N
```

Answer (score 0):

We can specify a condition such as

```
i1 <- with(df1, substr(GID, 1, 1) == 'N' & ColB == "")
df1$ColB[i1] <- "N"
```

---

Or use `grepl`

```
i1 <- with(df1,  grepl("^N", GID) & ColB == "")
df1$ColB[i1] <- "N"
```

---

If we want to replace in any of the columns

```
i1 <- with(df1, grepl("^N", GID))
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), "GID")
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], function(x) replace(x, i1 & x == "", "N"))
```

-output

```
df1
#  GID ColA ColB
#1   1    2    2
#2   2    3    4
#3   3    5    4
#4   4    6    5
#5   5    6    5
#6 NG1    8    N
#7 MG2    8    1
#8 MG3    8    1
#9 NG4    8    N
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(GID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "NG1", "MG2", 
"MG3", "NG4"), ColA = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    ColB = c("2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "", "1", "1", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, how to replace the "N" in the Same Row if any of the columns is empty

Comment: how to replace "N" if any columns of the same row are in empty

Comment: @kumar Please check the update with `lapply`

Comment: but it does not give me the output as a dataframe

Comment: @kumar If your initial dataset is `data.frame`, it does return data.frame

Comment: Column "GID" is not reflecting

Comment: @kumar Not clear though.  I showed an example with data as well in post along with output

Comment: Yes, I tried the same, but I am not getting the same output as you highlighted above as "-output.".  I am receiving output only without GID

Comment: Yes, I tried the same, but I am not getting the same output as you highlighted above as "-output.". I am receiving output only without GID

Comment: @kumar Sorry,  I couldn't reproduce the issue